# Including appcompact v7 toolbar error

Tags: java, android, android-toolbar, android-appcompat

I had made a common layout to include V7 toolbar in every activity , and its common class file `CommonToolbar.java` to handle its properties.

layout_common_toolbar.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_common"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/abc_action_bar_default_height_material"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimaryDark"/>
```

CommonToolbar.java

```
public class CommonToolbar {

    Activity activity;
    Toolbar toolbar;

    CommonToolbar(Activity activity, View view, String title) {
        super();
        this.activity = activity;
        toolbar = (Toolbar)view.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_common);
        toolbar.setTitle(title);
        toolbar.setTitleTextColor(activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
    }

    void setNav() {
        toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                activity.onBackPressed();
            }
        });
    }

    void setMenuListner() {
        toolbar.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new Toolbar.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                switch (item.getItemId()) {
                /*  case R.id.searchItem:
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Search", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case R.id.filterItem:
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Filter", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;*/
                }

                return true;
            }
        });

        toolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.common_toolbar_menu);
    }
}
```

Using it like:

In Layout

```
<include  android:layout_height="@dimen/abc_action_bar_default_height_material"
              android:id="@+id/includeSurgicalDetail"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              layout="@layout/layout_common_actionbar"/>
```

In Activity

```
View includedLayout = findViewById(R.id.includeSurgicalDetail);
CommonToolbar commonToolbar = new CommonToolbar(SurgicalDetail.this, includedLayout, pName);
commonToolbar.setMenuListner();
commonToolbar.setNav();
```

But I get the following error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.greyline.eswasthyaprojectv3/com.eswasthyaV3.SurgicalDetail}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.setTitle(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
```

Comment: post your activity xml

Comment: Why are u doing this odd way? Do everything in activity, not by other class and tell what happens.

Comment: To Avoid writing on option menu code and every thing multiple times, i thought this way would be more efficient. suggest me if any other way if you have...

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to write the same option menu code, you should `extend` the `Activity` instead.

Write a `BaseActivity` class like:

```
public class BaseActivity extends Activity{
    protected Toolbar toolbar;
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstaceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //initialize the Toolbar, set the menu listener, nav, etc
        toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar_common);
    }
}
```

Then for all the `Activity` that you want to have the share code, extends `BaseActivity` instead of the `Activity`.  So you do not need to write the same option menu code over and over.